# Google Analytics (UA): How the hell is it possible that the number of 'New Visitor' users is greater than the number of 'New Users'?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I understand that the opposite case may occur, that is, that the number of "New Users" is greater than that of "New Visitor" users, because there are times when the same person can be counted several times as a "New User", for example if you are browsing and your session passes to the next day at midnight.

Isn't there supposed to be at least the same number of "New Visitor" users as "New Users"? whenever the 'New visitor' users metric counter goes up, the 'New users' counter should go up too, right?

[image: how visitors and new users are counted]

I cannot explain the following screenshot.

[image: the data that I do not understand]

thanks you all